# how to prevent log if request matches in Apache

Tags: configuration, logging, apache-2.4

i'am trying to remove some request from Apache logs.
for example, if the request match "RunJobs&tasks=jobs"

i am trying to use

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(RunJobs&tasks=jobs)" dontlog
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined env=!dontlog
```

but request_URI doesn't contain the request it stop at the filename.

I checked the other possibilities, but none could help:

```
Remote_Host
Remote_Addr
Server_Addr
Request_Method
Request_Protocol
Request_URI
```

how to prevent log if request matches RunJobs&tasks=jobs ?

thanks

Comment: It's not a huge help, but the docs for the `SetEnvIf` directive says *Request_URI - the resource requested on the HTTP request line -- generally the portion of the URL following the scheme and host portion without the query string. See the [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive of mod_rewrite for extra information on how to match your query string.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `SetEnvIf Query_String` doesn't exist, this is a way to achieve it :

```
# Set an environment variable when the query string matches a certain string. 
# Modify the string you match against according to your requirements. 
# In this example any non empty query string matches. 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=dontlog:yes] 
# Use the env variable set above to remove from logging file. 
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined env=!dontlog
```

from http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/326145

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ - [E=dontlog:yes] ` is better